# How do I update an NFTs creator list?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I'mn trying to update a list of nfts to have a new secondary creator (the one with the 100% share). I don't think it's possible to update the first creator because I think the first creator is signed by the candy machine that created the nft? Anyway here's my code:

```
import { keypairIdentity, Metadata, Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js'
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { program } from 'commander'
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs'

program
  .command('update_creators')
  .description('Updates the creator of all nfts')
  .requiredOption(
    '-i, --input-file <string>',
    'Json file, list of NFT mint details'
  )
  .requiredOption(
    '-o,  --output-file <string>',
    'Output file for NFT addresses that failed to update'
  )
  .requiredOption(
    '-k, --keypair-file <path>',
    `JSON file containing private key of token owner`,
    '.cache/creator-keypair.json'
  )
  .option('-r, --rpc <string>', 'JSON rpc api url', defaultRpc)
  .action(async ({ inputFile, outputFile, keypairFile, rpc }) => {
    const connection = new Connection(rpc)
    const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
    const keypairFileContents = readFileSync(keypairFile, 'utf-8')
    const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
      Buffer.from(JSON.parse(keypairFileContents))
    )
    metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair))

    const nftMintAddresses = JSON.parse(
      readFileSync(inputFile, 'utf-8')
    ) as string[]

    let nfts = (await metaplex
      .nfts()
      .findAllByMintList({
        mints: nftMintAddresses.map(mint => new PublicKey(mint)),
      })
      .run()) as Metadata[]

    const newCreator = new PublicKey(
      'CUAwUE5N3TdHHHyPTHb3E5mpnpQFiRF6BcY8kEvJakfS'
    )
    const failedNfts: any[] = []

    for (const nft of nfts) {
      try {
        console.dir(nft, { depth: null })
        const newNft = await metaplex
          .nfts()
          .update({
            nftOrSft: nft,
            creators: [
              nft.creators[0],
              {
                address: newCreator,
                share: 100,
                authority: keypair,
              },
            ],
          })
          .run()
        console.dir(newNft, { depth: null })
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        failedNfts.push(nft)
        process.exit()
      }
    }
    writeFileSync(outputFile, JSON.stringify(failedNfts))
  })
```

Note, the `metaplex.use()` keypair I'm using is the same wallet used to create the candy machine and has authority to update the nfts, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ParsedProgramError [MetaplexError]: TokenMetadataProgram > Incorrect account owner
>> Source: Program > TokenMetadataProgram [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s]
>> Problem: The program [TokenMetadataProgram] at address [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s] raised an error of code [57] that translates to "Incorrect account owner".
>> Solution: Check the error message provided by the program.

Caused By: IncorrectOwner: Incorrect account owner

    at RpcClient.parseProgramError (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\rpcModule\RpcClient.ts:302:9)
    at RpcClient.sendTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\rpcModule\RpcClient.ts:87:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RpcClient.sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\rpcModule\RpcClient.ts:117:23)
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\utils\TransactionBuilder.ts:189:22)
    at async C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\utils\Task.ts:82:23
    at async Disposable.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\utils\Disposable.ts:34:14)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\src\cli.ts:263:24) {
  key: 'metaplex.errors.program.parsed_program_error',
  title: 'TokenMetadataProgram > Incorrect account owner',
  problem: 'The program [TokenMetadataProgram] at address [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s] raised an error of code [57] that translates to "Incorrect account owner".',
  solution: 'Check the error message provided by the program.',
  source: 'program',
  sourceDetails: 'TokenMetadataProgram [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s]',
  cause: IncorrectOwner: Incorrect account owner
      at Object.errorResolver (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\nftModule\plugin.ts:70:16)
      at RpcClient.parseProgramError (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\rpcModule\RpcClient.ts:299:35)
      at RpcClient.sendTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\rpcModule\RpcClient.ts:87:18)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async RpcClient.sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\plugins\rpcModule\RpcClient.ts:117:23)
      at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\utils\TransactionBuilder.ts:189:22)
      at async C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\utils\Task.ts:82:23
      at async Disposable.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\js\src\utils\Disposable.ts:34:14)
      at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\sol-tools\src\cli.ts:263:24) {
    code: 57
  },
  logs: undefined,
  program: {
    name: 'TokenMetadataProgram',
    address: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: b7065b1e3d17c45389d527f6b04c3cd58b86c731aa0fdb549b6d1bc03f82946>
    },
    errorResolver: [Function: errorResolver],
    gpaResolver: [Function: gpaResolver]
  }
}
```

And here's one of the NFTs I'm trying to update:

https://solscan.io/token/3woKb11Ajs9VkzHhMNkiyX5za1bV3STBmSaDHoQgmBKp#metadata

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try not parsing the NFTs to as Metadata[]?

Comment: @MarkSackerberg That would mean `nft` becomes `Metadata<JsonMetadata<string>> | Nft | Sft | null` and the `nftOrSft` argument can't accept potentially null values.

Comment: Also if I write the nft variable to file, it comes out like this: https://pastebin.com/f3FbZ1W7